# Application_Start event fired on every postback - lost session and cache

Tags: asp.net, session

ASP.NET WEB app, Framwork 4.5, VS 2012 prof update 4.

Problem: I have no Cache or Session. My Session variables are lost.

According to debugger, all Global.asax events are fired on every postback.

Every time I click a button or link sequence of events is:

```
Application_Start
Application_BeginRequest
Application_AuthenticateRequest
Session_Start
Session_End
Application_End
```

All that above event handlers are empty (defult).

`<sessionState cookieless="AutoDetect"  mode="InProc" timeout="20"/>`

```
Anonymous Authentication is enabled; 
Windows Authentication is disabled;
```

There is no underscore in hostname. 
Any idea why it destroys Session?

Comment: Thank you thekip for pointing right direction. App deployed to Azure works like a champ. Apparently there is something wrong with my development environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your application doesn't recycle on every request?

Check your event log, you might have a stackoverflow exception or that kind of thing.